# [rails]How to upload .doc file and .ai file(gem:s3_multipart)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upload

s3_multpart_uploader:
 `accept %w(wmv avi mp4 mkv mov mpeg)`

but, i wanna upload doc and ai file.
Is there any good way to do that?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Only to do add ai and docx to add.

accept %w(wmv avi mp4 mkv mov mpeg ai docx)